# Inserting into pivot table: ErrorException Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to insert data to a pivot table `order_serrvice` using arrays.  I follow this code: https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/master-detail-form-in-laravel-jquery-create-order-with-products/

OrderController:

```
$order = Order::create($data);
$services = $request->input('services', []);
$quantities = $request->input('quantities', []);
for ($service = 0; $service < count($services); $service++) {
    if ($services[$service] != '') {
        $order->services()->attach($services[$service], ['quantity' => $quantities[$service]]);
    }
}
```

The blade page:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select name="services[]" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- choose service --</option>
            @foreach ($services as $service)
                <option value="{{ $service->id }}">
                    {{ $service->name }} (${{ number_format($service->price, 2) }})
                </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            {{--<input type="text" name='service[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/>--}}
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

With `dd($request)`:

```
"services" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
      ]
      "qty" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "27"
        1 => "2"
      ]
      "price" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "489"
        1 => "4"
      ]
      "total" => "23647.69"
      "sub_total" => "13211.00"
      "vat" => "10436.69"
```

`dd($services[$service])`:

```
"1"
```

Error:

> ErrorException Undefined offset: 0
> $order->services()->attach($services[$service], ['quantity' => $quantities[$service]]);

Can any one help?

Comment: You are using `$request->input('quantities', [])`, but your form has `<input ... name='qty[]'`.  *quantities* != *qty*.  I am voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

instead of checking null check with isset. your for loop starts with 0 so initially it checking the zeroth value and there your array doesn't have that index. so change iteration value of loop starts

```
            for ($service=1; $service <= count($services); $service++) {
                            if (isset($services[$service])) {
                                $order->services()->attach($services[$service], ['quantity' => $quantities[$service]]);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: thank you for your respond, but that doesn't fixis the essue it gave me error like that ErrorException Undefined offset: 1

Comment: @SweetGarl please print $services[$service] once and die lets see wht value it holds

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the essue it is simple mistake I just replace the Quantity with qty in OrderController

```
   $order = Order::create($data);
$services = $request->input('services', []);
$quantities = $request->input('qty', []);
for ($service = 0; $service < count($services); $service++) {
    if ($services[$service] != '') {
        $order->services()->attach($services[$service], ['qty' => $quantities[$service]]);
    }
}
```